# SSL connection to PostgreSQL using OpenSSL failed in Cpp

Tags: c++, postgresql, ssl, openssl

I have been trying to connect to SSL enabled PostgreSQL server using OpenSSL libraries in C++. I am able to connect to PostgreSQL server and establish a non-SSL connection, but when I try to initialize SSL connection, Handshake process failed with following error:

```
Error
XXXXX:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:252:
```

On analyzing through Wireshark, I understood that the client closes the connection with alert protocol version (which means the client does not support server protocol version as said in RFC5246). Because Client Hello and Server Hello are done, the client does not respond.

I have tried following solutions,

1. Disabling SSL protocol versions other than TLS 1.2
2. Returned callback always true without any verification.

```
void ConfigureCtx(SSL_CTX* ctx)
{
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);
    SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback(ctx, TrueCallback, NULL);
    SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1);
}
```

3. Tried with different client methods

```
SSL_CTX* CreateSslCtx()
{
     SSL_CTX *ctx;
     ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_client_method());
     return ctx;
}
```

4. Also, Tried with OpenSSL package v 1.1.0 and 1.0.2.

PostgreSQL server details:

- PGSQL server version: 9.6.2
- PGSQL SSL protocol: TLS 1.2
- OS: Windows 7
- OpenSSL version: 1.0.2

Client Details:

- Client: Cpp Win 32 application
- OS: Windows 8.1
- External Libraries: Openssl v 1.1.0

Comment: Presumably you'd have the same problem if you used `openssl s_client` as a command. It's not a configuration problem, it's because a postgres client doesn't start with SSL_connect(), it negotiates first in clear text before optionally opting for TLS.  See `libpq` sources.

Comment: You should tell us the OpenSSL version on the PostgreSQL server as well.

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe, OpenSSL version on server is 1.0.2

Comment: Hi @DanielVérité, I sent SSL request message in clear text to Postgre server then start with SSLConnect still it fails with same error.